# How to put conditional statements in .jsp pages

Tags: jstl, conditional-statements

I need to have a conditional statement added on a .jsp page that identifies all authenticated pages in order to insert a specific tracking code in place. I am not accustomed writing any jstl but I have this so far

```
<c:if test='${not empty authenticatedUser}'>
  my  tagging code    
</c:if>
```

I would like to an extra condition in place that exclude a specific url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
<c:if test="${not empty authenticatedUser && url ne 'someUrl.html'}">
    my  tagging code    
</c:if>
```

Single quotes is coming two times. That might be creating an issue.

Answer (score 0):

EL expressions (the `${not empty authenticatedUser}`) can contain logical expressions like:

```
<c:if test='${not empty authenticatedUser and url ne "someUrl.html"}'>
    my  tagging code    
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I apply the logical expression, I get couple of error messages including: complaining about invalid location of text '}' in tag <c:if> and also undefined attribute about the URL